# How to disable cache in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache

I am creating a website, but I needed to do refresh several time to see the changes I made in website. Is there any option that I can use to disable cache in WordPress?

Comment: Which cache plugin are you using? If none, then the cache will be controlled via your web hosting - which host are you with?

Answer (score 41):

put below code in your wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_CACHE', false);
```

Comment: setting this flag still results in transients.

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: Yes.   WooCommerce.   This version doesn't seem to have any way to turn off using transients.

Comment: I do not think so this is the woocommerce issue.

Comment: Looking at wordpress documentation, there doesn't appear to be a way to disable transients. ( google comes up with results on how to clear them, but not to prevent them in the first place ).  Transients are a form of 'cache' stored in wp_options table.

Comment: maybe need to restart server?

Comment: I don't know why but didn't work for me.

Comment: It might be possible that your server is having their own cache configuration contact to them

Answer (score 2):

add code in your wp-config.php file.

```
//Add This Code In wp-config.php File To Enable Cache With Expiration

define('WP_CACHE', true);      // enable the cache
define('ENABLE_CACHE', true);  // enable the cache
define('CACHE_EXPIRATION_TIME', 3600);  // in seconds

//Add This Code In wp-config.php File To Disable Cache

define('WP_CACHE', false);     // disable the cache
define('DISABLE_CACHE', true);  // disable the cache
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more fine-grained control over what pages should not be cached, which ones should and for how long, etc. or you don't want to change the `wp-config.php` file, you can also try out the [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) plugin. I have used it for quite a while now and can recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

Use Disable cache in google chrome developer options.
Press F12, Go to Network > check disable cache.

Comment: He is referring to Server-side Caching: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens

Comment: I suffered the same issue while wp plugin development.Its work fine by disabling browser caching mentioned above,

Comment: Add this line in wp-config.php file  `define('WP_CACHE', false);`

Comment: Nice information to have during development. Thank you!